# Pattern compile .*? vs .*

Tags: java

I found a difference,but I can't explain it:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[+-]?\\d+.*?");
    Matcher m = p.matcher("+5.0h");
    System.out.println(m.matches());                                  //prints true

    Scanner in = new Scanner("+5.0h");
    while (in.hasNext()) {
        if (in.hasNext(p)) {
            System.out.println(in.findInLine(p));                      //prints +5
        }
    }
    in.close();

    System.out.println("6.0hgf".matches("[+-]?\\d+.*?"));   //prints nothing,it seemed that this sentence didn't execute,why this happened?
}
```

when I changed

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[+-]?\\d+.*?")
```

to

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[+-]?\\d+.*")
```

the following happened:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[+-]?\\d+.*");
    Matcher m = p.matcher("+5.0h");
    System.out.println(m.matches());                                  //prints true

    Scanner in = new Scanner("+5.0h");
    while (in.hasNext()) {
        if (in.hasNext(p)) {
            System.out.println(in.findInLine(p));                      //prints +5.0h
        }
    }
    in.close();

    System.out.println("6.0hgf".matches("[+-]?\\d+.*?"));   //prints true
}
```

so I'd like to know why this happened?

Comment: probably the last line of the second example is wrong. Its the same as in the first example. So the print result cannot be different!

Answer (score 1):

Well, `.` is any-character (not explicitly a decimal point) and then you have if followed by two different things, `*` which is a greedy quantifier for zero or more times and `*?` which is a reluctant quantifier for the same thing (see [Differences Among Greedy, Reluctant, and Possessive Quantifiers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/quant.html#difs)).

So the reluctant version `"[+-]?\\d+.*?"` allows reading a `+` in order to find a match and finds it with one or more digits (greedily). It then looks for any-character 0 or more times, and finds a match using any-character 0 times (so a trailing `.*?` is essentially pointless).

The greedy version `"[+-]?\\d+.*"` starts the same way, allowing the `+` in order to find a match with the digits; but then gobbles up all the any-characters it can get, which is of course the rest of the string.

---

Finally, the error in the first version (using `"[+-]?\\d+.*?"`) stems from how you use Scanner's [`hasNext(String pattern)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#hasNext%28java.lang.String%29) method, which is a comparison to the next token. Since the first iteration removes `"+5"` the next token remaining is `".0h"`, the conditions then evaluate as follows:

```
while (in.hasNext()) { //true, we have ".0h"
    if (in.hasNext(p)) { //false, ".0h" does not begin with +,-, or digit
        System.out.println(in.findInLine(p)); //no longer called, scanner doesn't advance
    }
}
```

So naturally the line following the loop is never reached.

By comparison, the in greedy version's (using "[+-]?\d+.*") first iteration `in.findInLine(p)` takes the entire String, so now `in.hasNext()` is false and the loop terminates.

Comment: Maybe you missed System.out.println("6.0hgf".matches("[+-]?\\d+.*?"));   //prints nothing,it seemed that this sentence didn't execute,why this happened? in the first case, in my eclipse,it did happen,and I don't know why

Comment: The line it self isn't wrong, What do you mean in the first cast it did happen?

Comment: I mean nothing was printed. Now I've found out that there should be a break in while loop, so I added else break to the while loop, then the program executed correctly.Thanks for answering.

Comment: @LamuelLee, Okay, well I think I've explained it all now. I apologize for not taking the comment more seriously, it looked somewhat tangential, as if it was just an issue and ".*? vs .*" was what you wanted to know.

Comment: Maybe I should describe my main confusion clearly. Anyway, the problem have been solved.

Answer (score 1):

the default behavior  of `*` is to match as many as possible , putting  a `?` after it makes sure it matches only as many as necessary.

for ex :

if i have string `"abc"` and i use `.*` , it will match the entire string but if i   change regex to `.*?` it will not match anything because `*` is 0 or more .

We can also take the example of `+` where if string is again `"abc"` and regex is `.+` it will match the entire string but if regex is `.+?` it will only match one character , in this case `a`.

Answer (score 0):

`.*` consumes as much chars as are sufficient to match (greedy)

`.*?` consumes the least number of chars as are sufficient to match

Your first example is matching a whole word:

```
Matcher m = p.matcher("+5.0h");
System.out.println(m.matches());
```

This means the match word is given and there is no space for different numbers of matched chars.

Your next example tries to find a pattern:

```
in.findInLine(p)
```

The latter pattern will find the least number of matched chars, the other the most number of matched chars.

The last example is not reproducible for me: `true` in both cases.

Answer (score 0):

The other answers have explained the difference between `.*` and `.*?`.  To answer your other question, why didn't the `System.out.println` execute in the first case: The problem is with your loop:

```
while (in.hasNext()) {
    if (in.hasNext(p)) {
        System.out.println(in.findInLine(p));                  //prints +5
    }
}
```

If there is more data to scan, but it doesn't match the pattern, this is an infinite loop.  Nothing will be consumed, and the code will keep checking `hasNext()` and `hasNext(p)` on the same input text, over and over.  So you'll need to rethink what you want your code to do if it can't match the pattern.

The reason this didn't happen when you used `.*` is that `.*` caused the rest of the input to be gobbled up.  This meant that `in.hasNext()` returned `false` the next time, because there was no more input.